# Specifying -std when compiling both C and C++ code

Tags: c++, c, clang

Suppose I have a codebase consisting of both C and C++ code, like so:

t.c:

```c
int derp(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

t.cpp:

```c++
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int derp(void);

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << derp() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With clang(++), I can both compile them in one go, like so:

```
clang++ -o t -xc++ t.cpp -xc t.c
```

However, if I now want to use non-standard features from e.g. `gnu++14` and invoke the compiler like so:

```
clang++ -o t -xc++ -std=gnu++14 t.cpp -xc t.c
```

I am greeted with an error:

```
error: invalid argument '-std=gnu++14' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'
```

Unlike `-x`, `-std` does not seem to work based on a file level, but to be a global option, because adding `-std=c11` like so:

```
clang++ -o t -xc++ -std=gnu++14 t.cpp -xc -std=c11 t.c
```

Simply gives me the "inverse" error, so to speak:

```
error: invalid argument '-std=c11' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'
```

And I know that I can compile each source file into an `.o` file separately and link them together afterwards (and yes, I'm automating the whole process anyway), but I cannot help but think that compiling with different standards per language should be possible. After all, clang supports compiling files in different languages together, and when doing that it would need separate values for the standards already, or not?

So, is there a way with clang(++) to manually specify standards when compiling both C and C++ code?

Comment: The usual way to do these kinds of things is prepare a Makefile that compiles each translation unit individually, using the appropriate options for C and C++ translation units; and have make run them all in parallel, which would be faster, of course. I'm sure you understand how improbable it is for large software libraries to be compiled manully, by hand, like this. This is what a Makefile is for: to compile a bunch of files, correctly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this should rly be an answer

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's precisely what I ended up doing in my case, and I have to admit that I cannot come up with an all too solid use case for this. Nevertheless, I have only 10 files that I'm compiling together, and even though I have a Makefile anyway, this being a single operation would've been much simpler than the current bunch of targets I had to add, complete with wildcard expansion for dependencies and intermediate files.

Comment: Well, this is what [GNU Automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) and [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) is for: to automatically generate the makefile, and autocreate the proper compilation dependencies. They have a pretty steep learning curve, but generally eliminate the need to manually write out a Makefile. They'll do it for you, starting with only a little bit more than a list of files to compile.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik A potential use case for doing them together is that I expect more optimizations are possible this way (I don’t think everything is available through link-time optimization, though I could be wrong). And I think that autotools is falling out of favor compared to other options like cmake, so for somebody just looking into such tools for the first time it might be better to start there.

Comment: That said, there are tools that can help in creating Makefiles.  For example, in CMake, about all you would need to do would be something like: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11) project(t) set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11) add_executable(t t.cpp t.c)`

Comment: 2021 -- LLVM 12 -- AFAIK if you do `clang t.c t.cpp` the outcome is executable named `t`. Default C std is `gnu17` and the default C++ std is `gnu++14`.  If you need e.g. c++17 you need to compile them separately and then link them. Just as advised in the answer below by @Lightness Races in Orbit.

Answer (score 4):

You can compile C, and you can compile C++.

You cannot compile as both C and C++.

Compile your C source files with C-appropriate flags.

Then compile your C++ source files with C++-appropriate flags (e.g. `-std=gnu14`).

Then link the results together to get an executable.

```
clang   -o a.o t.c
clang++ -o b.o t.cpp -std=gnu++14
clang++ -o t   a.o b.o
```

You cannot use the shorthand you've attempted to do both at once. It is designed as a shortcut for when all the flags and all the whatevers are the same. That's despite the magic of `-x` which sort of gets you close-ish.

Comment: “You cannot compile as both C and C++.” You obviously can, or `-x` would work differently. Can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: @DanielH: You can compile a source file as C. You can compile a source file as C++. You cannot compile a source file as both C and C++ at the same time. Of course this is not the whole story, as I pointed out myself, because there is a shorthand using `-x` that gets you close to what the OP wants to do. But, it is not a way of merging two completely different compilation commands into one. So _"you obviously can"_ no you still can't. I provided the solution.